# the following arguments are required

Tags: python

I have the Python script . What I'm trying to do is to test this code in colab

The problem is that the initial script requires arguments. They are defined as follows:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Pipeline to train a NN model specified by a YML config")
    parser.add_argument("-t", "--tag", nargs="?", type=str, help="Model tag of the experiment", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("-c", "--config", nargs="?", type=str, default="syndoc.yml", help="Config file name")
    parser.add_argument("-s", "--seed", nargs="?", type=int, default=4321, help="Seed number")
    parser.add_argument('-wt', '--with_test', action='store_true', help='Whether to run corresponding Tester')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    config = coerce_to_path_and_check_exist(CONFIGS_PATH / args.config)
    run_dir = MODELS_PATH / args.tag

    trainer = Trainer(config, run_dir, seed=args.seed)
    trainer.run(seed=args.seed)
```

the error

```
usage: trainer.py [-h] -t [TAG] [-c [CONFIG]] [-s [SEED]] [-wt]
trainer.py: error: the following arguments are required: -t/--tag
```

Comment: Your post is missing the context of what you are trying to do, e.g. what imports you are using, what the class Trainer is.

Comment: No question was provided in this post

Comment: "The problem is that the initial script requires arguments." So... supply some arguments? What exactly is the difficulty? If you actually don't know how to do that, then you don't have a programming question; you have a "how do I use my computer" question. You could try on https://superuser.com, but you might have better luck with, say, putting `supply arguments to program` into a search engine.

Answer (score 0):

Arguments are received when you run a program from the command line (shell, bash, cmd) and they enable effecting the program without changing it e.g. `my-program -varX 1` vs `my-program -varX 2`, you are not doing so, so instead you can remove that code and replace `args.config`, `args.tag` etc. with variables e.g. `config` and `tag` that you define and set to the values you want.

Answer (score -1):

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Pipeline to train a NN model specified by a YML config")
parser.add_argument("-t", "--tag", nargs="?", type=str, help="Model tag of the experiment", required=True)
parser.add_argument("-c", "--config", nargs="?", type=str, default="syndoc.yml", help="Config file name")
parser.add_argument("-s", "--seed", nargs="?", type=int, default=4321, help="Seed number")
parser.add_argument('-wt', '--with_test', action='store_true', help='Whether to run corresponding Tester')
args = parser.parse_args()

```
config = coerce_to_path_and_check_exist(CONFIGS_PATH / args.config)
run_dir = MODELS_PATH / args.tag

trainer = Trainer(config, run_dir, seed=args.seed)
trainer.run(seed=args.seed)
```

Comment: Hello, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help Thanks!